# Typescript + casting string as type and using the case of type

Tags: typescript

Let's say I got this type

```js
export type CoolType = 'Super' | 'Whatever' | 'Another'
// notice they all start with an uppercase letter
```

So right now, this returns 'super'

```js
console.log('super' as CoolType)
```

...but I want it to return the value given in the type, which would be "Super". How can I do that?

Comment: This is not constrained enough. What case matching rules apply (consider input: 'SuPeR') What if your input does not match any of the CoolType values? (Consider input 'imNotCool')

Comment: @jcalz answer is really good, but the way I think about it is that TypeScript is like a very advanced linter on top of JS. Once you hit runtime, it's just JS again, no matter what TypeScript said or complained about.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TypeScript's static type system is [erased](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/basic-types.html#erased-types) when TypeScript code is emitted to JavaScript code.  This includes [`type` aliases](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-aliases) such as `CoolType`, and [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) such as `as CoolType`.  TypeScript isn't really meant to add any runtime functionality above and beyond what some version of JavaScript gives you.  Your code above will compile to

```
console.log('super');
```

and there is no way that it could print anything but `"super"`.

Note that `"super" as CoolType` is a *type assertion* and not a runtime cast.  The term "cast" is unfortunately ambiguous, and so is best avoided.  A type assertion is supposed to be when you are telling the compiler what the type will turn out to be at runtime.  It's useful in situations where you know more information about the type of a value than the compiler can figure out.  It's a prediction, not a command.  And so `"super" as CoolType` means "I know you don't realize this, compiler, but `"super"` actually is of type `CoolType`"... which is a lie.  Oops.

---

Generally speaking, you should ask yourself "how could I do this in pure JavaScript" , and then write that code.  TypeScript can help give you stronger type guarantees and warn you when you make mistakes in development, but it will not fundamentally change what happens at runtime.  So one approach you could take at runtime is the following:

```
function toCoolType(s) {
  return ['Super', 'Whatever', 'Another'].
    find(c => c.toLowerCase() === s.toLowerCase());
}

console.log(toCoolType('super')) // Super
```

That would work, and while it's not as pretty as `"super" as CoolType`, it has the advantage of actually doing something.  Then, to turn that into TypeScript, you can add some type information:

```
function toCoolType(s: string): CoolType | undefined {
  return (['Super', 'Whatever', 'Another'] as const).
    find(c => c.toLowerCase() === s.toLowerCase());
}

console.log(toCoolType('super')) // Super
```

And the compiler will now understand that whatever comes out of `toCoolType()` is either a `CoolType` or `undefined`:

```
const ct = toCoolType(Math.random() < 0.5 ? "whatever" : "whenever");
if (ct) {
  console.log(ct.length); // 8
} else {
  console.log("wasn't cool") // wasn't cool
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9nANgFXNAvFA5AZQK6QBOWUAPtgOoAWAhsBAG4TFnYCCAdnMFc1gLAAoIQDM8HAMbAAlnA5RgceElSQAFAGcAXFA3BC0jgHMAlDuUo0rcQBMIIwxBtQA3kKhRCEYHkLy1ANq4BHwANJS09EzE4Vic3LzEALpQNBpQEnJ6JgB07h5QDhw2ahJQ6AB8GTmKADJwAO7MMGkQaibl6JgaNXD1TYQtGm0mJgDcQgC+QkKZHBpIEDmIcEZqihaqbVgaIcSjUAD0h1D4RDOCc3oZwOUKSgiW6gCydFQ5hDTFcAC27VAAHigAAYcgBWKAAfigACIGpFGMwYVAdHDeBxEYQYeMhNIRFBSsAOm5BB4rotlqtCcsIMYeOMjicABxTKAQRDDVz5cmIJYrNZwtIcLC3TJIbGMqANIUijKPKZCIA)

Comment: *"It's a prediction, not a command."* Ah, good to know. Great answer!